# OpenWhisk- How to upload package actions?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk

I am new to OpenWhisk. I am currently using AWS Lambda(node.js) to generate custom tokens. Lambda has an option to upload the Zip file as a package. Does OpenWhisk have a similar option? I couldn't find any doc related to such an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenWhisk now (24th October 2016) supports uploading a zip file with your Node.js source files and NPM modules to run as an Action.

This [documentation page](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk/blob/master/docs/actions.md#packaging-an-action-as-a-nodejs-module) has details on how to use this feature.

```
$ wsk action create packageAction --kind nodejs:6 action.zip
```